# Sorting Array with ICompare

Tags: c#, arrays, class, sorting, icomparer

This is my first question here, so when i do something wrong, pls be so kind and just say it. So. I have found this in a textbook. Its the Class of an Object Array Sort programm. It's exact the thing i need but it's really poorly explained in the book and i can't get clever out of it. So could someone maybe explain it detailed for me?This would really help me.

```
class Person : IComparable                     
{
    private string name;
    public Person()
    {
        name = "EMPTY";
    }
    public Person (string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    }

    public string NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
    public int CompareTo( object oneObject)   
    {
        Person comparePerson = (Person)oneObject;             
        return (name.CompareTo(comparePerson.name));    
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name of the Person: " + name;
    }}
```

Comment: I posted on here before asking for a section of code to be explained to me. The question was not well received. I have found, for this kind of question; ASP Forums is a good place to turn. https://forums.asp.net/ :-)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place for questions like this. Here we focus on finding solutions to specific problems, not on explaining code parts.

Answer (score 0):

This code is example for implementation of `IComparable` interface. You can use it in cases when you want use `Sort()` method on array, where instances is not values (classes, structs). 
This part of code describe sort principle for computer, how it should sort array of Person instances:

```
1.    public int CompareTo( object oneObject)   
2.        {
3.            Person comparePerson = (Person)oneObject;             
4.            return (name.CompareTo(comparePerson.name));    
5.        }
```

At line 3 Cast argument (it will be compared with current instance) to Person class. It's unsafe because you can get InvalidCastException if `oneObject` isn't 
Person class.

At line 4 comparing `Name` of current instanse with name of `oneObject` argument
Properti `Name` is string. String has implementation of `IComparable` interface, and you use it.

When you call Sort() method on Array it will compare elemnts (using `CopareTo(arg)`) one-to-one, and arrange they based on results.